# How do I add shortcuts to the right side of the task bar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, shortcuts

I had to reload my PC from scratch via Reset. It is Windows 10. I'm slowly adding apps and shortcuts. On my previous system I had added some shortcuts that are way to the right of the normal place. These are shortcuts to files. Now I can't figure out how I did that.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: Was it a 'New Toolbar' or Quick Launch Toolbar? Right click Taskbar --> Toolbars --> New Toolbar?

Comment: That did make a new task bar but it says "Contacts". How  to I change that to a specific set of files? I tried that again and it says it has to point to a folder. I think I had two files that I was point to.

Comment: The toolbar can have any folder as its source. So create a folder anywhere under your user profile, then create or move the shortcuts you want on the toolbar to the folder,  and create the toolbar from that folder.

Comment: Thanks, I think I just remembered wrong. So I created a folder and a toolbar to point to it.